UTF-8 encoding with LangChain JSONLoader
I have a UTF-8 encoded JSON file containing German "Umlaute", for example:
{
    "json": {
        "0": {
            "attr1": "schöne deutsche Wörter",
            "attr2": "text"
        },
        "1": {
            "attr1": "Hallo",
            "attr2": "Ä Ö Ü"
        }
    }
}

My goal is to implement retrieval using Langchain. But when I load the JSON data using Langchains JSONLoader the encoding seems to get messed up. I could not find a parameter to set the encoding explicitly.
My Python code:
from langchain_community.document_loaders import JSONLoader

loader = JSONLoader(
    file_path='test.json',
    jq_schema='.json[]',
    text_content=False)
data = loader.load()
print(data[0].page_content)

Output:
{"attr1": "sch\u00f6ne deutsche W\u00f6rter", "attr2": "text"}

Expected Output:
{"attr1": "schöne deutsche Wörter", "attr2": "text"}

Any advice?

JSON is UTF-8 encoded, why do you expect to see non-encoded characters ? Btw. print(json.loads('{"attr1": "sch\u00f6ne deutsche W\u00f6rter", "attr2": "text"}')['attr1']) works well.

The output looks like it's JSON encoded? A Python dict would use single quotes by default, so I'm guessing data[0].page_content is implicitly encoded to JSON again? And Unicode escape sequences are a perfectly valid way to encode those characters. Maybe not your preferred way, but the output is equivalent to your input.

Thanks, I was hoping it's really just a matter of output presentation. Maybe this is a stupid question, but just to be sure: Passing values like these to an embedding model (OpenAI) will work as expected? The tokens "schöne" and "sch\u00f6ne" are identical for the LLM as well?

If the LLM parses the JSON with a compliant JSON parser: yes. If it just takes the JSON string as is: obviously no.
